# How to stream AWS cloudwatch logs to ELK stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Elastic's ELK stack for log monitoring and analysis which is running on an EC2 cluster. I want to send all the logs from my Cloudwatch log groups to the ELK. One solution which seems feasible is to store all the logs in a S3 bucket and use S3 input plugin to send logs to Logstash.

Is there a way we can directly stream logs from Cloudwatch to my ELK stack by using either lambda functions or Kinesis or any other service?

Note: I'm not using AWS Elasticsearch, I'm using Elastic's ELK stack.

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/blueimp/aws-lambda/tree/master/cloudwatch-logs-to-elastic-cloud

Comment: @Val this looks good. I'll try to implement it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Elastic Stack 6.5 has been released on Nov 14th and a new beat called [Functionbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-overview.html) allows you to stream your Cloudwatch logs easily to ES.

Comment: I'll look into it. Ty :)

Comment: @ShivRajawat, any success?

Comment: @Kourosh Look into this https://github.com/blueimp/aws-lambda/tree/master/cloudwatch-logs-to-elastic-cloud

Comment: @ShivRajawat, great, thank you!